# How to run a for loop to run regressions by dummy variables

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, linear-regression, dummy-variable

I have the following code:

```r
reg <- lm(Y ~ x1 + x1_sq + x2 + x2_sq + x1x2 + d2 + d3 + d4, df)
```

Where all x_i are continuous variables and d_i are mutually exclusive dummy variables (d1 is present but exclude to avoid perfect multicollinearity). Rather than including the dummy variables, I want to run separate regressions for each dummy variable == 1. I wish to achieve this through a loop in the following form:

```r
dummylist <- list("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4")
for(i in dummylist){
   if(i==1){
      ireg <- lm(Y ~ x1 + x1_sq + x2 + x2_sq + x1x2, df)
   } else {
      Unsure what to put here
   }
}
```

My three(?) questions are:

1. in the first section of the -if- function, do I just include "i" before "reg" for my code to generate results "d1reg, d2reg, etc."? and,
2. included in the code above, what would I put after the -else- statement?
3. This all begs the question, is putting an if-else statement **within** the -for- loop the wrong approach/is there a more appropriate loop?

Sorry if this is too much, please let me know if it is and I can cut it down or separate into multiple questions. I could not find a similar question, probably as I am rather new to running loops in R and don't know what to look for.

Comment: Yes, takeout the ifelse as you don't want any dummies for that regression - just run it outside the loop, and remove d1 from your list. (Also at the moment, `i == 1` will never be true; i is "d1", "d2", "d3" or "d4", but never 1.) 
No, you can't just add i to variable names. But you can do `regs <- list()` before the loop and then do `regs[[i]] <- lm(...)` within it. In general, if you have many similar things, you should keep them in a list, not in several variables with similar names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in the first section of the -if- function, do I just include "i" before "reg" for my code to generate results "d1reg, d2reg, etc."?

Short: **No**

In R there are many data types. One of the more versatile once is the `list` object, which can store any type of object. Alternatively one could create an `environment` to store the lists within, but that is a bit overkill.

If you know roughly how many elements should be in your list, the easiest is to initialize it prior to your loop as

```
n <- 3
regList <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
# Optional naming:
#names(regList) <- c("d1 reg", "d2 reg", "d3 reg")
```

In your loop you then fill in your list iteratively:

```
for(i in seq_along(regList)){
   regList[[i]] <- lm(...)
}
```

2. what would I put after the -else- statement? This all begs the question,

It is not entirely clear what you want here. Either you want to 'only' include the seperate dummy variables. For this the simplest is likely to save your `formula` and updating it iteratively.

```
form <- Y ~ x1 + x1_sq + x2 + x2_sq + x1x2
for(i in seq_along(regList)){
   #paste0 combine strings. ". ~ . + d1" means take the formula and add the element d1 
   form <- update(form, as.formula(paste0(". ~ . + d", i)) 
   regList[[i]] <- lm(form, data = df)
}
```

or maybe you are actually trying to run separate regressions on the subset where `d[i] == 1`. This can actually be done with `lm` itself

```
form <- Y ~ x1 + x1_sq + x2 + x2_sq + x1x2
d <- list(d1, d2, d3)
for(i in seq_along(regList)){
   #Using the subset argument
   regList[[i]] <- lm(form, data = df, subset = which(d[[i]] == 1))
   #Alternatively:
   #regList[[i]] <- lm(form, data = subset(df, d[[i]] == 1))
}
```

**Disclaimer:** It is not entirely clear if d1, d2, d3 is a part of df. In this case the example below would work

```
   regList[[i]] <- with(df, lm(form, subset = which(d[[i]] == 1)))
```

3. is putting an if-else statement within the -for- loop the wrong approach/is there a more appropriate loop?

In this case it is not clearly the correct approach. But it isn't the wrong approach either in all circumstances. Here it just doesn't serve a clear purpose. And note that `i in dummylist` would return `"d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"` as the variables have been quoted, rather than directly placed within the list.

However another thing to address, is whether you have transformed the variables yourself, before performing your linear regression. Note that `R`'s internal function allows you to do this directly in the `formula`, and doing this will allow it to help you avoid dummy-mistakes, such as testing variables for which an interaction exists, unless it is very very much what you wanted to do. For example i assume `x1_sq = x1^2`. Maybe `d1, d2, d3` are all contained in a variable `d`? In these cases you should use the original variables as shown below:

```
lm(formula = Y ~ poly(x1, 2, raw = TRUE) + poly(x2, 2, raw = TRUE) + x1:x2, data = df ) #+d if d1, d2, d3 is part of the formula
```

`poly` being the second order polynomial and `raw = TRUE` returning the parameters as `x1 + I(x1^2)` rather than the orthogonal representation.

If one does this, the output of `drop1`, `anova` etc. will take into account that it should not test the first order variables to the second order interactions.

Comment: I have 4 dummy variables, I want to run a regression on observations where d1==1 and all others ==0, and then d2==1 and all others ==0, ... and so on. They are dummy variables for crop (wheat, rice, etc.) and I want to run a wheat regression then a rice regression... etc. I think I can work it out from this, thank you very much.

Comment: Also, you are correct in that my d1, d2, d3, are contained in a _string_ variable d. I just created dummy variables for each value of the string d. This was done as I am practicing R, my regular package is Stata and I want to get better at R

Comment: @Brennan (1) That was my bet. Stata (i believe SAS as well) requires explicit dummy variable creation, where R's implementation handles both ordinal and nominal factor variables automatically. Instead of creating your own variables i suggest performing most transformations directly via the `formula` class. `y~log(x) + x*z` will for example make `y = log(x) + x + z + x:z` while `poly(x,2)` creates `x + x^2` (albeit orthogonalized unless `raw=TRUE` is specified). If `d` contains your dummy you could subset by `d == "d1"` or the appropriate value.

Comment: (2)  I have yet to find a sufficiently nice overview and explanations of formulas, but the basics are: `+` adds a term as is. `-` removes a term from an existing formula `-1` removes intercept. `:` creates interactions `*` creates interactions plus additive effect `|` lets you model conditional similar to `a + a:b`. Certain expressions like `log(x)` works as expected, but more complicated stuff might need the "as is" operator `I( ... )` which forces evaluates of the expression prior to use. For example `I(sqrt(x)^(2/3))` would evaluate correctly while `sqrt(x)^(2/3)` will not.

Comment: (3) the latter is due to the fact that `(a+b+c)^2` is evaluated as `a+b+c+a:b+a:c+b:c`, meaning `^n` is the interaction of 2nd order. All of his is somewhat poorly described and even worsely illustrated in the examples in the documentation, which can be gotten by executing `help(formula)` in R. I hope that this helps somewhat, otherwise SO is a good place to find answers to the questions that often pop up when Stata sometimes isn't enough.